# Вопрос по enum. Почему обязательно писать ";"?

Tags: java, enum

```
public enum Class1000{
    ;   // почему это обязательно писать? 
    public static void main(String[] args) {

    }
}
```

Почему обязательно писать ";" в теле enum до того как вызвать экспериментальный psvm или во время обьявления полей или переопределения методов реализуемых интерфейсов и тд...?

Известно, что до этого знака компилятор все написанные имена считает перечислением.

Comment: Вы же вроде сами и ответили на свой вопрос в последнем предложении, нет?)

Comment: @iksuy Я указал на результат проверки на практике, но надо на теоретическом уровне знать как оптимально сформулировать то, что происходит и возможно даже лучше понимать что происходит в данной ситуации имея под рукой оптимальное описание на теоретическом уровне.

Comment: есть подозрение, что я что то мог упустить из внимания во время интуитивного предположения сути роли ";" в данном коде.

Comment: Честно говоря, не совсем понимаю зачем ты класс main засунул в enum. А точка с запятой нужна только потому, что enum сначала ждёт перечисление каких-либо значений. Вот здесь можно [прочитать](https://javarush.ru/groups/posts/2260-enum-prakticheskie-primerih-dobavlenie-konstruktorov-i-metodov)

Comment: @Blacit чисто ради интереса, чтобы увидеть можно ли так делать или нет, так как не редко в OCA,  OCP тестах бывают подобные странные и на первый взгляд бессмысленные вопросы, вот и приходится делать не только те проверки в которых видишь  смысл  но и те, в которых ты не видишь смысла но надо, так как мало ли что.

Comment: Я выше обновил комментарий, думаю, что станет яснее. Если да, то сделаю как ответ, чтобы другие люди видели.

Comment: @Blacit, Ссылка годная. Спасибо.  но нет теоретического описания, пожалуй как я понял, выше мое замечание на основе результата моей проверки и в правду является полноценным ответом. Или мне это показалось и есть что добавить?

Comment: Нет, это действительно является полноценным ответом, добавить даже нечего. Это достаточно исчерпывающе.

Comment: Хорошо. Значит все лучше чем я предполагал.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

У вас действительно в вопросе порождён ответ.

Enum ждёт перечисления изначально, а вы ему показали знаком ";", что оно закончено (даже, если там ничего нет) и в итоге всё будет выполнять в обычном порядке.

Можно почитать [здесь](https://javarush.ru/groups/posts/2260-enum-prakticheskie-primerih-dobavlenie-konstruktorov-i-metodov) о Enum.